# Successful HTTP POST 200 to FCM but no notification on Android app

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

This small program written in Java should send a notification to my android app through firebase cloud messaging. Currently, the connection with FCM seems successful according to the limited response code I receive (200, OK). However, no notification is received on the Android app.

When using another 3rd party java app for the same server key the notification is delivered successfully on the same Android application, in this case it is not.

I think the problem lies in the device token part, I don't need to send the notification to a specific device, I want the notification to be sent to all/any available device as long as it reaches my device.

```
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class AndroidPush {

    /**
     * Replace SERVER_KEY with your SERVER_KEY generated from FCM
     * Replace DEVICE_TOKEN with your DEVICE_TOKEN
     */
    private static String SERVER_KEY = "AAA*******APA91bH2i5FGIhBhMj3YEf0yCq*********************************************************************";
    private static String DEVICE_TOKEN = "caNraerHp9M:APA91bEKyYHV9ymsFh4xXyii****************";


    /**
     * USE THIS METHOD to send push notification
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String title = "My First Notification";
        String message = "Hello, I'm push notification";
        sendPushNotification(title, message);
    }


    /**
     * Sends notification to mobile
     */
    private static void sendPushNotification(String title, String message) throws Exception {
        String pushMessage = "{\"data\":{\"title\":\"" +
                title +
                "\",\"message\":\"" +
                message +
                "\"},\"to\":\"" +
                DEVICE_TOKEN +
                "\"}";
        // Create connection to send FCM Message request.
        URL url = new URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + SERVER_KEY);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        // Send FCM message content.
        OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(pushMessage.getBytes());

        System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println(conn.getResponseMessage());
    }
}
```

**RESPONSE CODE:
200
OK**

**ANDROID APPLICATION**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // defining the constant for the tag in onTokenRefresh
    private static final String TAG = "TFA_service";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        onTokenRefresh();
        //get all server-FCM-Android notifications
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("ALL");

    }

    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Toast.makeText(this, refreshedToken, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        System.out.println(refreshedToken);

        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        System.out.println("Registration.onTokenRefresh TOKEN: " + refreshedToken );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had also face the same problem.I also did not recive the notification so I add following line of code during json making,

```
{
   "content_available": true,
   "priority": "high",
   "to": "efxA1bbRGrE:APA91bGmmYrGQBJ6QrM-LOimnbnwMo3WL9MQxJuyuyYdieph0o_P32oouovPB72SFO6ruyyubZKI-RCLAoE1xKQHZFcyVnVfJp92dUAN3-JUcWISplxjqoMjlAzAV6HIdM0n56yw0FxXr7OX44ZzwJ4N",
   "notification": {
       "title": "Strawberry",
       "body": "Hello This is notification test from FCM"
   }
}
{
   Authorization: key=AAAAf0KIvao: APA91bE9eCULa0POdBP94xEPtUeazF_j2XGFcz6GH49RroNmsAmrWt1QG8WYpDFaIoipRtK0Cdn1_2Vz94OoWUlV-4H2IDxwtXM1hAuxcmXn-tcspEbODzsKpcXJjfhaoK2HWTTLHoZlSender: id=546uy577u1042uyuy98Content-Type: application/json
}
```

So just use the above code in your java file and it may help.

Comment: It seems my issue is that I am trying to send it to the FCM device token whilst having not implemented the "        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
" I rather send it using a topic.

Comment: @Rami if my suggestion helps you in any way then you should accept my answer.

Comment: I tried using your code in my file but don't know how to incorporate it in the code, (i'm a beginner).

Comment: @Rami my code just shows the contents  you have to use to preparing json for contacting to server ,you have to use your  syntax to prepare that json.

Comment: @Rami did you get the answer??
I have the same issue which you have raised
Authorization key also should be sent as json data?? or as normally with `setRequestProperty`?

Comment: @Rami Here is my pushMessage can you help me in finding mistake??

`JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
     message.put("to", deviceTokenList.get(0));
     message.put("priority", "high");
     message.put("content_available", true);

     JSONObject notification = new JSONObject();
     notification.put("title", "Java");
     notification.put("body", "Notification do Java");

     message.put("notification", notification);

String pushMessage = message.toString();
`